# Qt API to get application user data save location on iOS & Android

Tags: android, ios, qt, save

I am using *commercial* `Qt 5.6` with app running on `android` & `iOS`. I want to save user data i.e `.png` & `.jpeg` files that my app generates. And, I want to keep the files **private to the application** so that other apps are not able to access them.

As I learn, the location I should use on `iOS` is
`<Application_Home>/Documents`

And, the location I should use for `Android`, it is
`/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<app_package_name>`.

*Is there an API in Qt which can return me the these file locations on iOS & android without having to deal with any java or swift code ?*

Comment: looking for a better answer to this question. Tried `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)`  & `QStandardPaths::standardLocations( QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation ).value(0)` but none of them worked on iOS. Basically I get a blank string. Do I need to add any permissions in my `Info.plist` for `iOS` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) Class.

Comment: as per [this ios official link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), `Documents` folder inside App's `Data Container` is where I should store user saved files. How can I use `QStandardPaths` to access that particular `Documents` folder ?

Comment: I tried `QStandardPaths::writableLocationQStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)` which returns `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxx/Library/Application Support`. From [iOS official link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), it looks like there is a `Documents` folder I should target to store user files ? How can I get that using `QStandardPaths` ?

Comment: It depends. Apple says about /Library/Application Support:
"Use this directory to store all app data files except those associated with the user’s documents. For example, you might use this directory to store app-created data files, configuration files, templates, or other fixed or modifiable resources ...So this might be what you want. Otherwise, I guess you want GenericDataLocation instead of AppDataLocation

Comment: says what ? if you read it says `/Documents` in Application directory's data bundle is the location save such files. I can get that link by adding a "/Documents" to the path returned from Qt & it works as I tested. that should be ok ?

Comment: I was still editing my comment when you replied. Hope this is what you need.

Comment: What is `GenericDataLocation` ? Is it located inside app bundle ? I am looking for a path inside app private file system